# Regular expression in Jmeter for a json reponse

Tags: jmeter

How do i write the regular expression for the json response.

My json response is  "publisher":"/api/web/publishers/194".

From this response i want to get only the numeric value i.e 194. Some one pls help in getting it?

Answer (score 0):

If "194" is the only integer in your response than your regex can be limited to just '(\d+)`

If you response contains more digits, you'll need to be more specific, like

`"publisher":"/api/web/publishers/(\d+)"`

So something like:

- Reference Name: `publisher`
- Regular Expression: `"publisher":"/api/web/publishers/(\d+)"`
- Template: $1$

Will extract "194" and store it in "publisher" JMeter Variable. You'll be able to refer to it as `${publisher}` later in Thread Group.

Going forward if you'll need to extract something from more complex JSON structures I'd recommend consider using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) - the extractor lives in "Extras with Libs Set" package.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for more information and XPath to JSON mapping.